# Why does generator raise an exception when a loop that iterates over it is interrupted?

Tags: python, exception, generator

```
def gen():
    try:
        yield 1
        yield 2
    except:
        print('hi')
def func():
    for x in gen():
        return x
print(func())
```

This code prints `hi` and then prints `1`. Why doesn't it just print `1`? What exception was raised?

Comment: why the console prints 'hi' then prints 1.why not just returns 1?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What exactly are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please explain in your question what output you expected to see and what output you actually got?

Comment: I'm not seeing that behaviour.   I get a ```1``` immediately.

Comment: Your edit made the question much worse. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Your *for* loop returns the first value yielded from the generator - in this case 1. What were you expecting/hoping would happen? Why the *try/except* in the generator? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @ewokx Did you really run OP's code and it didn't print _hi_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `func` retrieves the first element from the `gen` generator.
After that, `func` has a `return` statement.
As a result, `func` execution terminates, causing the `gen` generator to exit as well.
When a generator's [`close`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.close) method is called, it raises a [`GeneratorExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#GeneratorExit) exception,
which is the exception caught in this case.
That is why it prints `hi`.
After that, program continues; `func` returns `1` and this value is printed in the final line of code.

The `generator.close` method is invoked because the generator dies.
After your `for` loop, there are no remaining references to the generator object.
If you assign the generator to a variable `a = gen()` and you don't fully consume its iteration, you can trigger the raising of `GeneratorExit` by directly calling `a.close()` or by killing the object using `del a`.

On the other hand if you allow your generator to complete its execution, it will not raise `GeneratorExit`.
When the loop `for _ in gen(): pass` completes, it successfully concludes the execution of the `gen` generator, resulting in a `StopIteration` exception  that is handled by the `for` loop.
But it will not raise `GeneratorExit` because, by the time `close` is called, the execution of `gen` has already concluded.

---

It is interesting that `GeneratorExit` does not inherit from [`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception) but from [`BaseException`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException).
If were you write `except Exception: print('hi')`, only `1` would be printed.
By so, you can manage any exception raised in your generator without interrupting its execution:

```
def gen():
    for i in (1, 2):
        try:
            yield i
        except Exception:
            pass
```

If you were to use `except: pass` instead, it would catch `GeneratorExit` and permit the execution of `gen` to continue yielding another value.
Which should not happen according to [`generator.close`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.close) documentation:

> If the generator yields a value, a [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError) is raised.

In fact, you would encounter a *RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit*

Comment: Very helpful ! If I replace 'return x' with 'pass' ,then 'hi' wont be printed.So the for loop actually handles the GeneratorExit?I thought the for loop just handles the StopIteration.

Comment: If you write `pass`, no `GeneratorExit` exception is raised because `gen()` completes its execution. It is not interrupted by `generator.close`.